# How to know if a point is analytics or not?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have the equation

```
 y" + [(x-x^3)/x]y' +[(sinx)/x]y = 0
```

My x nought it equal to 0.

I know this is a singular point because my denominator is equal to zero.  Then to check if it's analytic or not, I did

```
 x*P(x) which is equal to (x-x^3)
 x^2*Q(x) which is equal to x(sinx)
```

How do I determine if this is analytic?

Comment: 0 is not a singular point.  The sinx/x term goes to 1; the $(x-x^3)/x$ goes to 1 - $x^2$.  The question is whether the solution of this ode is analytic.  You need to show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold.

Comment: So what you're saying is that since sinx/x is equal to 1 and the other goes to 1-x^2, this would be ordinary point?

Comment: sinx/x goes to 1 in the limit as x approaches 0.  So formally you must replace the function f(x) = sinx/x with a new function g(x) = sinx/x where x $\ne$ 0; g(x) = 1 where x = 0.  The new function g(x) can be shown to be analytic.  So far we have not said anything about y being analytic or not.  You either have to solve this equation, or at least show that y satisfied the Caucy-Reimann equations (which might be easier).

Answer (score 2):

The point $x=0$ is a regular singular point, since

> $$ \lim_{x\to 0}xP(x)=\rm{finite}=0, $$

and

> $$  \lim_{x\to 0}x^2 Q(x)=\rm{finite}=0 $$

Comment: Okay, so basically, if my denominator is equal to zero, then it's not analytic correct?

Comment: @asik: The point $x=0$ is a singularity, but we call it a "regular singular point". On the other hand, if it is not a regular singular point, then we call it "irregular singular point".

Comment: What if my xP(x) equaled 1/x ?  Then that wouldn't be regular correct?

Comment: @asil: then $x=0$ is irregular singular point. By the way, have you studied Frobeninus Method?

Comment: So since this is an Ordinary Point as Betty commented above, then this equation would just be an Ordinary point and analytic?

Comment: @asik: What I gave you in my answer is the way we use to check for the type of singularity. On the other hand, we do not have to do this test for the ode $y''+xy'+\sin(x)y=0$. Do you see why?

Comment: Because the denominator does not equal 0?

Comment: @asik: Because the functions $x$ and $\sin(x)$ have no singularities.

Comment: I think I understand a tad bit more.  However, I will relook this over and hopefully understand it fully.  Maybe you might still be on tomorrow if I might have any other roadblocks or difficulties.  Thank you.

Comment: @asik: You should review the meaning of a singularity of a function at a point and the test for regular singular point of an ode.

Comment: @asik -- there may some confusion of terminology here.  Strictly formally speaking sinx/x has a singularity at zero, because of the 0 denom.  However it is a "removable" singularity.  What that means is that you can replace the function with the limit of sinx/x (namely 1) at the point 0. With the replacement the function is analytic at 0.  I tend to be imprecise about the difference between a function with a removable singularity, and one which does not have a singularity.  Maybe someday someone will tell me why the distinction is important.

Answer (score 0):

It's either analytic or singular.

**HINT** To check if it's regular, multiply $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ by $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x)$.

Comment: What do you mean it's either analytic or singular?

Comment: analytic = p(x) is nonzero. Otherwise, it is singular.