# Solve $y'' - y/x + y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can you solve the following differential equation,

> $$y'' - a\frac{y}{x} + by = 0,$$

Or

> $$y'' - y(\frac{a}{x} - b) = 0,$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Please note that there is no $y'$ - this is not a Bessel differential equation.

Is there an exact solution to this equation?

What method would you use?

Comment: [Separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Comment: I have formatted your question. But do you mean $y''-ay/x+by=0$ or $y''+ay'/x+by=0$, which seems more likely?

Comment: Hypergeometric Functions.

Comment: The solution turns out to be ugly, but if you try using separation of variables, this might work.

Comment: y" - ay / x + by = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maple solves $y'' \left( x \right) + \left( {\frac {a}{x}}-b
 \right) y \left( x \right) =0$ in terms of the Whittaker M and Whittaker W:
$$
{ C_1}\,
{{\bf M}_{a/2\sqrt {b},1/2}\left(2\,\sqrt {b}x\right)}
+{ C_2}\,
{{\bf W}_{a/2\sqrt {b},1/2}\left(\sqrt {b}x\right)}
$$
or in terms of the Kummer M and Kummer U:
$$
2\,\sqrt {b}x {{\rm e}^{-\sqrt {b}x}}\left( 
{{\rm U}\left(1/2\,{\frac {2\,\sqrt {b}-a}{\sqrt {b}}},\,2,\,2\,\sqrt {b}x\right)}
{ C_2}+
{{\rm M}\left(1/2\,{\frac {2\,\sqrt {b}-a}{\sqrt {b}}},\,2,\,2\,\sqrt {b}x\right)}
{ C_1} \right) 
$$

Comment: Yes (but note that $a$ and $b$ have been changed to $-a$ and $-b$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the comments

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, $x=0$ is a [regular singular point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590472/how-to-know-if-a-point-is-analytics-or-not), then you can use [Frobenius method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).

Comment: I am seeking to solve y" - ay / x + by = 0. No y' in the middle.

Comment: @Heisenberg: See the edit.