# Singular points to second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

working through a differential equation problem where I am being asked to find and classify the singular points to the differential equation:

$$(x^3-2x^2+3x)^2\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)+x(x-3)^3\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)-(x+1)y=0$$

So I discovered that the roots are x=0,1-i(2)^(1/2), and 1+i(2)^(1/2). Where im struggling is that I dont understand how we can check regularity with the two complex roots. How would you go about this?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590472/how-to-know-if-a-point-is-analytics-or-not).

Answer (score 0):

The points $z=1\pm i\sqrt{2}$ which are the complex roots of $(x^3-2x^2+3x)^2$ are NOT regular singular points, since each of them is a root of multiplicity 2 in the coefficient of $y''$, while they not not annihilate the coefficient of $y'$.

Meanwhile $z=0$ IS a regular singular point of the equation.