# Solve the equation $3xy''+5y'+3y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the equation $$3xy''+5y'+3y=0$$ i have to find two independent solutions for $x>0$. And i have to see if this solutions are analytic at 0.

**My approach:** I try to solve this  problem using series but i'm stuck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x=0$ is a [regular singular point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590472/how-to-know-if-a-point-is-analytics-or-not) and you need to use [Frobenius method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).